# crontab does not upload file via ftp script

Tags: linux, ftp, cron

I Write script that make a zip file with /var/www Directory And mysqldump db
upload it via ftp
change mode to executable file And put It in cron tab

but file doesn't upload !!!

```
#!/bin/bash

mysqldump -u root -h localhost -p123456 --all-databases > /tmp/test/databases.sql
tar cfz /tmp/test/databases.sql /var/www /tmp/test/zip.tar.tgz

ftp -n <<EOF
open $server
user $user $password
put /tmp/test/zip.tar.tgz
EOF
```

Put it in crontab

- - - - - ./script.sh

but when crontab has been worked , just the zip file was created and it doesn't uploaded

Comment: Where do $server, $user and $password come from? If you set them in your .profile, they won't be available to cron scripts. Also, you should give the filename on the server as well, or the whole path (/tmp/test/zip.tar.tgz) will be used - if /tmp/test doesn't exist, ftp can't put the file. And lastly, the order of the file names in your tar is wrong; the first argument after cfz is the tar file to be created.

Comment: I define this variable in top of the script, and zip file is correct because it works correctly.

Comment: BTW, it is not a *zip* file but a compressed *tar* archive. I would name it `/tmp/backup.tar.gz` instead of the confusing `/tmp/test/zip.tar.tgz`

Comment: +1 to @GuntramBlohm's syntax remark; are you sure it's working? I would use `tar czf /tmp/backup.tar.gz /tmp/test/databases.sql /var/www` (incorporating @BasileStarynkevich's renaming suggestion).

Comment: yes it works, i surprise about this but it's real
i terminal czf has been worked and cfz does not worked
and in script czf does not worked !!!!!!!

Answer (score -1):

You could use [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) to make the FTP upload.

And you should worry (with your current script) about the output (both *stdout* and *stderr*) of your `ftp` command. It probably has been sent by mail from `cron`

Also, you could use the [logger(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logger.1.html) command in your script.

For instance, you might add

```
logger -t backupcron -s user=$user passwd=$passwd server=$server
```

before your `ftp` and check (in `/var/log/messages` or whatever log files you have) that the variables are indeed what you believe they are.

Don't forget that `cron` is not starting your cronjob with the same environment than you have in a terminal. In particular `$server`, `$user`, and `$passwd` are *not* defined.